# Pass Data from HTML Table to Modal and then to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a index.php in which i have a Table with data from a MySQL database. Each row in the table has the data for the corresponding data in my database. Each row has a delete button. I want to show up a Modal and ask for permission to delete the entry. If the accepting Button is pressed i want to pass the id of that row to a delete.php script where the deletion is handled. So how do i pass the id for a row from my table to the modal and then to my delete.php. I know that i need jquery and ajax for it but im a total beginner with them. Im using bootstrap.

this is my button:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#delModal" data-toggle="modal 
               data-row-id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" " >Delete</a>
```

and my modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Entry</h5>
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="id" value=""/>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Are you sure that you want to delete the selected Entry? There is no way to restore the deleted data!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="accDelBtn">Yes, delete.</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="disMdBtn" data- 
 dismiss="modal">No, abort.</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

my jquery/ajax garbage try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#delBtn').on('click', function() {
$('#deleteModal').show();
});

$('#disMdBtn').on('click', function(){
    $('#deleteModal').hide();
});

 $('#accDelBtn').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: { id: $row['id'] }
           })  
        });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So what is the result of your attempt? Are you getting errors? (you've checked your browsers Javascript console, right?) If so, what are the exact errors? What debugging have you already done? You're asking for help, but you're not saying what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an attribute for each ‍`button` tag called `record_id` and the record ID should be stored in it.

for example :

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" id="delBtn" record_id="1">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
```

And when the button ('#delBtn') is clicked, I get the ID and save the variable.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var id = null
        $('#delBtn').on('click', function() {
             id=$("#delBtn").attr("record_id")
            $('#deleteModal').show();
        });

        $('#disMdBtn').on('click', function(){
            $('#deleteModal').hide();
        });

        $('#accDelBtn').click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete.php",
                data: { id: id }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

And when I click on the button ('#accDelBtn'), I will send it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the id of the row globally. Add a variable at the beginning of your script:

```
var rowToDelete = null;
```

Then, when you click a delete button, update it in the click handler:

```
rowToDelete = ID_TO_DELETE;
```

Finally, you can transmit it as:

```
data: { id: rowToDelete }
           })  
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have placed an hidden field with name attribute as "id", which you can use for doing further actions.

Check below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#delBtn').on('click', function() {
        $('#deleteModal').show();
        // setting value of hidden input field by using currently clicked link data-row-id attribute
        $('#deleteModal').find('input[name="id"]').val($(this).attr('data-row-id'));
    });

    $('#disMdBtn').on('click', function(){
        $('#deleteModal').hide();
    });

    $('#accDelBtn').click(function() {
        // retrieving value of hidden input field
        var id = $('#deleteModal').find('input[name="id"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: { id: id }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have just setted value of hidden field, on anchor tag click. And retrieving that hidden field value when doing ajax call.

Comment: your solution works but I would argue that using HTML (and a transient one at that) to pass data is prone to errors in jQuery environments + beginner devs. Let's try to instill some best practices ;)

Comment: Thanks for taking time out, do you know any better options then please share, because me too keen to enhance skills.